# Apache Ignite & Kubernetes: Zones

Tags: .net, kubernetes, ignite

Trying Ignite with Kubertenes deployment options.

1. Is it zone-aware? Cannot find any docs & configuration about this.
2. Can I connect the Kubernetes cluster via an external client? I'd like to connect via [C# client](https://apacheignite-net.readme.io).

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

1. Broadly speaking, Ignite assumes all your nodes are close to one another. You could make it aware of multiple zones by using custom affinity functions, but it's not straight-forward. There are also third-party solutions (I work for GridGain who provide one) that support data centre replication, etc. that would work in this situation
2. Yes. I would suggest that thick clients should be part of your Kubernetes infrastructure (since they become part of the Ignite cluster topology), but you can connect a thin client just by opening the right ports. You can use Kubernetes load balancing / round robin to connect to any node

Comment: May be you can help me with a drill down of this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61062929/apache-ignite-zonerack-aware-parititons. Thanks in advance!