# Apache Ignite zone(rack)-aware parititons

Tags: ignite

I'm battling to configure Apache Ignite to distribute partitions in zone-aware manner. I have Ignite 2.8.0 with 4 nodes running as StatefulSet pods in GKE 1.14 split in two zones. I followed [the guide](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/affinity-collocation#section-crash-safe-affinity), and [the example](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cache/affinity/rendezvous/ClusterNodeAttributeAffinityBackupFilter.html):

- Propagated zone names into pod under AVAILABILITY_ZONE env var.
- Then using Web-Console I verified that this env var was loaded correctly for each node.
- I setup cache template in node XML config as in the below and created a cache from it using `GET /ignite?cmd=getorcreate&cacheName=zone-aware-cache&templateName=zone-aware-cache` (I can't see affinityBackupFilter settings in UI, but other parameters from the template got applied, so I assume it worked)

To simplify verification of partition distribution, I the partition number is set to just 2. After creating the cache I observed the following partition distribution:

[image]

Then I mapped nodes ids to values in AVAILABILITY_ZONE env var, as reported by nodes, with the following results:

```
AA146954 us-central1-a
3943ECC8 us-central1-c
F7B7AB67 us-central1-a
A94EE82C us-central1-c
```

As one can easily see, **partition 0 pri/bak resides on nodes 3943ECC8 and A94EE82C which both are in the same zone**. What am I missing to make it work?

Another odd thing, is then specifying partition number to be low (e.g. 2 or 4), only 3 out of 4 nodes are used). When using 1024 partitions, all nodes are utilized, but the problem still exists - 346 out of 1024 partitions had their primary/backup colocated in the same zone.

Here is my node config XML:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

  <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">

    <!-- Enabling Apache Ignite Persistent Store. -->
    <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
      <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
        <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
          <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
            <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
          </bean>
        </property>
      </bean>
    </property>

    <!-- Explicitly configure TCP discovery SPI to provide list of initial nodes. -->
    <property name="discoverySpi">
      <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
        <property name="ipFinder">
          <!-- Enables Kubernetes IP finder and setting custom namespace and service names.  -->
          <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder">
            <property name="namespace" value="ignite"/>
          </bean>
        </property>
      </bean>
    </property>

    <property name="cacheConfiguration">
      <list>
        <bean id="zone-aware-cache-template" abstract="true" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
          <!-- when you create a template via XML configuration, you must add an asterisk to the name of the template -->
          <property name="name" value="zone-aware-cache*"/>
          <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
          <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
          <property name="backups" value="1"/>
          <property name="readFromBackup" value="true"/>
          <property name="partitionLossPolicy" value="READ_WRITE_SAFE"/>
          <property name="copyOnRead" value="true"/>
          <property name="eagerTtl" value="true"/>
          <property name="statisticsEnabled" value="true"/>
          <property name="affinity">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.affinity.rendezvous.RendezvousAffinityFunction">
              <property name="partitions" value="2"/>  <!-- for debugging only! -->
              <property name="excludeNeighbors" value="true"/>
              <property name="affinityBackupFilter">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.affinity.rendezvous.ClusterNodeAttributeAffinityBackupFilter">
                  <constructor-arg>
                    <array value-type="java.lang.String">
                      <!-- Backups must go to different AZs -->
                      <value>AVAILABILITY_ZONE</value>
                    </array>
                  </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
              </property>
            </bean>
          </property>
        </bean>
      </list>
    </property>

  </bean>
</beans>
```

**Update:** Eventually `excludeNeighbors` false/true makes or breaks zone awareness. I'm not sure why it didn't work with `excludeNeighbors=false` previously for me. I made some scripts to automate my testing. And now it's definite that it's the `excludeNeighbors` setting. It's all here: https://github.com/doitintl/ignite-gke. Regardless I also opened a bug with IGNITE Jira: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-12896. Many thanks to @alamar for his suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend setting `excludeNeighbors` to `false`. It is `true` in your case, it is not needed, and I get correct partitions mapping when I set it to `false` (of course, I also run all four nodes locally).

Environment property was enough, did not need to add it manually to user attributes.

Comment: I'm quite sure I tried with and without `excludeNeighbors`. I will recheck again, however I don't see why should it interfere, unless it's a bug.

Comment: How many partitions did you use? How do you verify correctnes? Can you please post node config XML and REST cmd you use to create the cache?

Comment: I did not use REST, I used SQL. I can retry with REST.
I had 16 partitions and I confirmed correctness visually.

Comment: Can you please share SQLcommand then and the node config as well?

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/alamar/e195241332a686dfa5f584678b54cb6f
Please note that I used GridGain Visor GUI to assess partition distribution as opposed to Web Console.

Comment: Still works for me if I create cache via REST. Please note that in your example you're creating a cache with exactly the same name as your template, I renamed it into zone-aware-cache1. I have also rechecked it with Web Console with same result.

Comment: Eventually `excludeNeighbors` false/true makes or breaks zone awareness. I'm not sure why it didn't work with `excludeNeighbors=false` previously for me. I made some scripts to automate my testing. And now it's definite that it's the `excludeNeighbors` setting. It's all here: https://github.com/doitintl/ignite-gke. Regardless I also opened a bug with IGNITE Jira: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-12896

Comment: I think than, when running in docker/k8s, Ignite can't tell one server from another and consider them all neighbors, and stopping partition picking logic at that.

Comment: Well, in containers servers have difference IPs and consistently different hostnames. Let's see what developers say.

Comment: It seems to me, the problem is that your config explicitly set `excludeNeighors` flag: `<property name="excludeNeighbors" value="true"/>`. In that case, `RendezvousAffinityFunction` ignores affinity backup filter.

Comment: By the way, the example https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cache/affinity/rendezvous/ClusterNodeAttributeAffinityBackupFilter.html looks correct, and does not specify this flag.

Comment: Yes, but reading about `excludeNeighors` it looks like a good setting in general, for non-localdev setup. I'm familiar with similar settings from other databases, so I set it right away because I was preparing production-like template for running ignite. Anyhow, I saw you acknowledged the problem in the bug tracker, so I think we can wrap it up here. Thank you again for your help on this.